# como identificar tag disable com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `input` com a classe `form_campos`, preciso fazer o jQuery identificar quando o `input` tiver a tag `disabled` e troque a class para `form_disabled`

```css
.form_campos {
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #484848;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form_campos:hover, .form_campos:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form_disabled, .form_disabled:hover, .form_disabled:focus {
    border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form_campos" name="nome" disabled>
```

Comment: Em que momento você deseja fazer essa verificação? Ao carregar a página, ao clicar em um botão, ao digitar o texto, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seletor [:disabled](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) para isso. Desta forma você irá obter todos os `inputs` desabilitados, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('input:disabled').removeClass('form_campos').addClass('form_disabled');
```

```css
.form_campos {
  height: 31px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #484848;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.form_campos:hover,
.form_campos:focus {
  border-color: #0091FF;
}

.form_disabled,
.form_disabled:hover,
.form_disabled:focus {
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form_campos" name="nome" disabled><br/>

<input class="form_campos" name="nome">
```

Comment: Boa resposta, uma ideia seria você colocar o seletor para pegar os inputs com a class form_campos, ao invés de todos os inputs, pois ele pode ter outros inputs que não se aplicam a isso.

Comment: Olá @JuniorNunes tudo bem? Eu iria colocar, mas aí vi a sua resposta. Não deseja continuar com ela abrangendo esta parte?

Comment: @JuniorNunes parece que deu certo, dessa forma apenas os input com disabled foram alterados.

Comment: Eu deletei porque no fim de tudo ficou muito parecida com a sua, até mesmo com essa alteração rss, vou pensar em algum outro jeito e ai reposto.

Comment: @Randrade obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou

Comment: @JuniorNunes Não tem problemas ser parecida, dependendo do contexto a sua até se encaixa melhor mesmo.

Comment: @HugoBorges O que ele disse é que se você possuir algum `input` em sua página que não deveria seguir essa lógica, ele não seria excluídos. Assim, adicionar um outro seletor, como a classe, ajudaria a garantir que somente os `inputs` selecionados teriam essa alteração.

Comment: @Randrade ok, entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `toggleClass` também:

```js
$('.form_campos:disabled').toggleClass('form_campos');
```

```css
.form_campos {
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #484848;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form_campos:hover, .form_campos:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
input:disabled {
    border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form_campos" name="nome" disabled>
```

Dessa forma quando o `input` tiver a classe form_campos ele vai retirar, e quando não tiver ele vai adicionar. Assim você elimina o uso da outra classe.